# SQL ambiguous columns

Tags: sql

Im working with two tables here.

[image]

The idea to take these tables and display the course number, course name, prerequisite, and prerequisite name.

However as you can see I have to deal with ambiguity.

So far I ran this query

```
SELECT c.course_name, p.course_number, course_name AS "prereq_course",prereq
FROM rearp.course  c, rearp.prereq  p
WHERE c.course_number = p.course_number;
```

and got this...

[image]

Looks like all is good except you may notice that the course name for the prerequisite is just a copy of the course.

How would I fix this issue?

Comment: I recommend you explicitly state your `JOIN` instead of using the old multiple tables with commas syntax (which is deprecated in most databases anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that you're wanting to look up the prerequisite course and get it's name.

You need to join back to the course table a second time:

```
SELECT c.course_name, p.course_number, c2.course_name AS "prereq_course",p.prereq
FROM
   rearp.course  c
      inner join
   rearp.prereq  p
      ON c.course_number = p.course_number
      inner join
   rearp.course c2
      on
         p.prereq = c2.course_number
```

(I've also switched to ansi join syntax, rather than the `,` style)

Comment: yep that got it I made some slight changes it appears the syntax I used confused me.